# replace one char string into many chars string in php

Tags: php, string, math, replace

how do i replace one word in a string to couple words. what do i mean by this is, i try to replace 'x' to something else

```
 <?php

    $equation = 'sin(x)';
    $length = strlen($equation);

    for($i=0; $i<$length; $i++) {

        if($equation[$i] == 'x') {

            $equation[$i] = substr_replace('x','90',$equation);
            echo $equation.'<br>';
            calc($equation);
        }
    }
?>
```

however, it only read the first value which is 9. but when i put only one digit for example

```
 <?php
    $equation = 'log(x)';
    $length = strlen($equation);

    for($i=0; $i<$length; $i++) {

        if($equation[$i] == 'x') {

            $equation[$i] = substr_replace('x','1',$equation);
            echo $equation.'<br>';
            calc($equation);
        }
    }

?>
```

it can received and evaluate the equation using some other codes. so, is there a way?

Comment: thank you very much. never thought about that. i did use str_replace at first, but never thought it didn't work because of the loop. thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

you should not loop the string manually ! functions are made to do that !

Use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
<?php
$equation = 'log(x)';

str_replace("x","90", $equation);

echo $equation.'<br>';

calc($equation);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi and Welcome to stackoverflow. You don't need to loop your string. Existing function replace a part of string.

[str_replace(search, replace, subject)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

[preg_replace(pattern, replacement, subject)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

... and more.

In your case, you can just do something like that :

```
$equation = 'sin(x)';
$equation = str_replace('(x)', '('.$yourValue.')', $equation);
```

EDIT/NOTE : I don't just replace 'x' but '(x)' in case or you have more of one x in your string and you want replace just the parameter of your function sin or log etc. Use preg_replace if you need more accuracy

Comment: brilliant. i'm actually want to let user put their own value. i'll try later.

Comment: If it's resolve your problem, please accept this response. :). Open an other topic if you need help for get the value from the input user